# R package dependencies fails check

Tags: r, dependencies

I am updating a package, where the package depends on another package. The code worked under R 3.1.0, but not under 3.4.0.

So, **how do I fill in "DESCRIPTION", when my packagage depends on another package** (mgcv).

I want this dependency to be installed when my packagage is installed, if it is not already installed.

As I read "Writing R extension" I should write:

> Depends: mgcv

in the "DESCRIPTION"-file

In R 3.1.0 this worked fine, but now when I want to update my package to R 3.4.0
and run check I get the error message:

> ** checking package dependencies ... ERROR Package required but not available: 'mgcv' See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R
>   Extensions' manual.*

Any help is truly appreciated

Comment: Do you have mgvc installed for 3.4 on your system

Comment: When I have it installed the package passes the check, but the problem is, when the check is runned by CRAN it fails the check. I  therefore get an email with "package xx does not pass the incoming checks automatically, please see the pre-test" There the error message is "** checking package dependencies ... ERROR Package required but not available: 'mgcv' See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.*"